# First letter in capital "part I, ..., IV", chapters and sub-sections automatically in [scrbook]?

Tags: chapters, capitalization, scrbook

i am struggling to find a way to capitalize the first letter in "part", "chapter" and "sub-sections" automatically... so far i've used a manual workaround "\texorpdfstring{\MakeUppercase Xx}" which does the work in the document body, but for example in the pdfbookmark it doesn't show anylonger the first letter.

Is there a way to automatically change that "part I, II, III, IV, V ,...", Chapters and sub-section all start with capital letter (first sentence only) and the pdfbookmark is also shown correctly on pdf afterwards?
Same goes for Appendixes...

thanks you all!

```
   \documentclass[oneside,11pt, a4paper, footinclude=true, headinclude=true, cleardoublepage=empty]{scrbook}
    \usepackage[linedheaders,parts,pdfspacing,dottedtoc]{classicthesis}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{acronym}
    \usepackage[a4paper, hmargin={2.8cm, 2.8cm}, vmargin={2.5cm, 2.5cm}]{geometry}
    \usepackage{eso-pic} % \AddToShipoutPicture
    \usepackage{graphicx} % \includegraphics
    \graphicspath{
        {Pics/PDFs/}
        {Pics/JPGs/}
        {Pics/PNGs/}
    }
    \usepackage{color, colortbl}
    \definecolor{LightCyan}{rgb}{0.88,1,1}
    \definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.9}
    %\usepackage{subfig}
    \usepackage{subcaption}
    \usepackage{textcomp}
    \usepackage{footnote}
    \usepackage{verse}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \usepackage{cmap}
    \usepackage[T1, T2A]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
    \usepackage{csquotes}
    \usepackage{bookmark}
    \usepackage{longtable}
    \usepackage{array}
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{times}
    \usepackage{lingmacros}
    \usepackage{color, colortbl}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    \usepackage{pdfpages}
    \usepackage{footnote}
    \definecolor{mygray}{rgb}{0.86,0.86,0.86}
    \makesavenoteenv{tabular}
    \makesavenoteenv{table}
    \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2.0}
    \def\signed #1{{\leavevmode\unskip\nobreak\hfil\penalty50\hskip2em
      \hbox{}\nobreak\hfil(#1)%
        \parfillskip=0pt \finalhyphendemerits=0 \endgraf}}
    
        \newsavebox\mybox
        \newenvironment{aquote}[1]
          {\savebox\mybox{#1}\begin{quote}}
              {\signed{\usebox\mybox}\end{quote}}
    
    
    \renewcommand{\cfttabpresnum}{} % get rid of "table"
    \renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{}
    
    \newcolumntype{S}{>{\footnotesize}l} % define a new column type for \small
    
    \usepackage{mdframed}
    
    \usepackage{array}
    \usepackage{threeparttable}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \newcommand{\tabhead}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
    \newcommand{\rothead}[1]{\rotatebox{45}{\tabhead{#1}}}
    
    \usepackage{tipa}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    \newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
    \usepackage{breqn}
    \usepackage{setspace}
    %\doublespacing
    % or:
    \onehalfspacing
    \usepackage{ragged2e}
    
    
    %for R code
    \usepackage{listings}
    \lstset{    language=R,                       
    basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily, numbers=left,
    stepnumber=5,                    
    numbersep=5pt, backgroundcolor=\color{white}, frame=single,   
    captionpos=b,                        keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    commentstyle=\color{red},
    breaklines=true,
      postbreak=\mbox{\textcolor{red}{$\hookrightarrow$}\space}}
    
    
    %Box around fig
    \usepackage{wrapfig, framed, caption}
    
    
    
    %\usepackage[backend=biber,style=nature,dashed=false,sorting=nty, maxcitenames=2]{biblatex}
    
    \usepackage[%
      backend=bibtex      % biber or bibtex
    ,style=authoryear    % Alphabeticalsch
    %,style=numeric-comp  % numerical-compressed
     ,sorting=nyt        % no sorting
     ,sortcites=true      % some other example options ...
     ,bibencoding=ascii
     ,block=none
     ,indexing=false
     ,citereset=none
     ,isbn=true
     ,url=true
     ,doi=true            % prints doi
     ,natbib=true         % if you need natbib functions
    ]{biblatex}
    
    \addbibresource{references.bib} %Imports bibliography file
    
    \def \ColourPDF {Images/ku-farve.pdf}
    \def \TitlePDF   {Images/ku-en.pdf}
    
    
    \subject{ 
      \vspace{2.5cm}
     % \scriptsize{A thesis presented to the Faculty of Science in partial fulfillment of the requirements for the degree} \\
      \Large{Master of Science in } \\}
    
    \title{
    \vspace{1.0cm}
    \Large{Title}
      \vspace{0.5cm} \\}
    
    \author{
      \Large\textbf{Name Surname} \\
      \texttt{email address}
      \vspace{4.5cm} \\
      \large{Supervisors: }\\
    \textbf{Name surname}\\
    \large{Co-supervisors: }\\
    {\textbf{Name surname}\\\vspace{.01in}}
    \textbf{Name surname}\\
    \vspace{1cm} \\}
    \date{October 20th, 2020}
    
    
    
    \begin{document}
    \pagenumbering{roman}
    \AddToShipoutPicture*{\put(0,0){\includegraphics*[viewport=0 0 700 600]{\ColourPDF}}}
    \AddToShipoutPicture*{\put(0,602){\includegraphics*[viewport=0 600 700 1600]{\ColourPDF}}}
    \AddToShipoutPicture*{\put(0,0){\includegraphics*{\TitlePDF}}}
    \clearpage\maketitle
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \newpage
    \include{FrontBackMatter/dedication}
    
    \include{FrontBackMatter/acknowledgements}
    
    \include{FrontBackMatter/abstract}
    
    \include{FrontBackMatter/contents}
    
    \include{FrontBackMatter/abbreviations}
    
    %\include{FrontBackMatter/symbols}
    
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    
    
    
    \part{Project description}\label{Part:I}
    \include{Projectdescription/Introduction}
    \include{Projectdescription/Background}
    
    
    \part{\texorpdfstring{\MakeUppercase Da}ata validation and 
    \texorpdfstring{\MakeUppercase Li}ifetime Correction method}\label{Part:II}
    \include{Datav_lifetime/Datavalidation} \label{chap:Datavalidation}
    \include{Datav_lifetime/Methodology} \label{chap:Methodology} 
    \include{Datav_lifetime/Results0} \label{chap:Results0}
    
    \part{\texorpdfstring{\MakeUppercase Pr}reliminary analysis}\label{part:III}
    \include{PreliminaryAnalysis/Methodology1} \label{chap:Methodology1}
    \include{PreliminaryAnalysis/CA} \label{chap:Results0} 
    \include{PreliminaryAnalysis/PCA} \label{chap:Results2}
     
    
    \part{\texorpdfstring{\MakeUppercase Ap}ppendices} \label{part:VI}
    \include{Appendices/AppendixA} \label{chap:appendixA}
    \include{Appendices/AppendixB} \label{chap:appendixB}
    
    
    
    \medskip
    
    \printbibliography[
    heading=bibintoc,
    title={Bibliography}
    ] 
    
     
    \clearpage
    
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Why don't you do the capitalization your self? It is just as easy to type `c` as it is to type `C`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are losing the first letter as `\texorpdfstring` takes two arguments, the tex version for the document and the version for the pdf bookmark, so

```
\texorpdfstring{\MakeUppercase Li}ifetime
```

is

```
\texorpdfstring{\MakeUppercase{L}i}{i}fetime
```

and has no L in the string used for the bookmark, you could use

```
\texorpdfstring{\MakeUppercase{L}i}{Li}fetime
```

But (with no test example that shows a problem) it would appear that this is equivalent to simply using

```
Lifetime
```

so your `\part` can be

```
\part{Data validation and  Lifetime Correction method}
```